# Importing .blend files into netbeans

Tags: blender

How can we import blender models into netbeans for use? I have jmonkeyengine 3 installed for netbeans 7.3 but havent found any good tutorials on importing.

Comment: What do you mean by "importing"? NetBeans doesn't have to know the models, but instead they will have to be loaded at runtime by the code you create in NetBeans + JMonkey.

Answer (score 1):

We do not use the `.blend` files. They are `Blender` projects and cannot be used directly. You have to export them to a usable format like `.OBJ` files.

[image]

And you use the asset manager in JME3 to load an obj model.

```
assetManager.loadModel("path/to/model.obj");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: and do the models need to be uv mapped? or is it enough to give them a material?
im sorry but i am very new at java 3D so forgive any such foolish questions.

Comment: im doing as you suggested but its giving me the static/non static access issue error? any help?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not a user of JME3. I gave that code by seeing at the docs.

Answer (score 0):

.blend files are not supposed to be used in games directly. You should first export them to another format (obj, 3ds, own custom format..) and use that in your game instead.
.blend files (blender project files) are to 3D models what .psd files (Photoshop project files) are to 2D pictures. You wouldn't put a Photoshop project file on the web, but use jpeg, png, etc. instead.
While .blend files are great for editing purposes, they store lots of useless information, e.g. your game doesn't care about layers. Such features make .blend files complex and slow to load in your game.

You should research whether one of the existing formats is good enough for you ("supports enough bone weights" and other requirements), then pick one to export to, as described in http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Data_System/Files/Export
If none of the existing formats is good enough for you, you might want to install a 3rd party export plugin for blender or write your own exporter. You will then need to teach your game engine to load the chosen file format.